# Improve performance for SELECT statement to retrieve single record from table with 1.1 million rows (including related tables) PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-design, amazon-aurora

Disclaimer: I am using Entity Framework Core, so I am somewhat restricted in what shape the query below can take.

I have a large customer database (1.1 million records) and am using an API to select a single customer by mca_id and bring back the customer and all their related data from contact_information, address, and so on. It's currently taking around 5 - 700ms which seems very slow for retrieving a single record.

Here is the query (designed to bring back all information related to this customer. Note that Entity Framework Core (.NET/C#) enforces the ORDER BY at the bottom, so there's not much I can do about that).

```
SELECT
    t.customer_internal_id,
    t.business_partner_id,
    t.created_date,
    t.customer_type,
    t.date_of_birth,
    t.first_name,
    t.gender,
    t.home_store_id,
    t.home_store_updated,
    t.last_name,
    t.loyalty_db_id,
    t.mca_id,
    t.status,
    t.status_reason,
    t.store_joined,
    t.title,
    t.updated_by,
    t.updated_date,
    t.updating_store,
    c0.contact_internal_id,
    c0.contact_type,
    c0.contact_value,
    c0.created_date,
    c0.customer_internal_id,
    c0.updated_by,
    c0.updated_date,
    c0.updating_store,
    c0.validated,
    a.address_internal_id,
    a.address_line_1,
    a.address_line_2,
    a.address_type,
    a.address_undeliverable,
    a.address_validated,
    a.country,
    a.created_date,
    a.customer_internal_id,
    a.postcode,
    a.region,
    a.suburb,
    a.updated_by,
    a.updated_date,
    a.updating_store,
    m.customer_internal_id,
    m.channel_id,
    m.created_date,
    m.opt_in,
    m.updated_by,
    m.updated_date,
    m.updating_store,
    m.valid_from_date,
    c1.customer_internal_id,
    c1.channel_id,
    c1.type_id,
    c1.created_date,
    c1.opt_in,
    c1.updated_by,
    c1.updated_date,
    c1.updating_store,
    c1.valid_from_date,
    e.customer_internal_id,
    e.card_number,
    e.card_design,
    e.card_status,
    e.card_type,
    e.created_date,
    e.updated_by,
    e.updated_date,
    e.updating_store
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.customer_internal_id,
            c.business_partner_id,
            c.created_date,
            c.customer_type,
            c.date_of_birth,
            c.first_name,
            c.gender,
            c.home_store_id,
            c.home_store_updated,
            c.last_name,
            c.loyalty_db_id,
            c.mca_id,
            c.status,
            c.status_reason,
            c.store_joined,
            c.title,
            c.updated_by,
            c.updated_date,
            c.updating_store
        FROM
            customer AS c
        WHERE
            c.mca_id = '2701159742879@priceline.com.au'
        LIMIT
            1
    ) AS t
    LEFT JOIN contact_information AS c0 ON t.customer_internal_id = c0.customer_internal_id
    LEFT JOIN address AS a ON t.customer_internal_id = a.customer_internal_id
    LEFT JOIN marketing_preferences AS m ON t.customer_internal_id = m.customer_internal_id
    LEFT JOIN content_type_preferences AS c1 ON t.customer_internal_id = c1.customer_internal_id
    LEFT JOIN external_cards AS e ON t.customer_internal_id = e.customer_internal_id
ORDER BY
    t.customer_internal_id,
    c0.contact_internal_id,
    c0.contact_type,
    a.address_internal_id,
    m.customer_internal_id,
    m.channel_id,
    c1.customer_internal_id,
    c1.channel_id,
    c1.type_id,
    e.customer_internal_id,
    e.card_number
```

The following are the primary / foreign keys:

- Customer     PRIMARY KEY ("customer_internal_id")
- Address  PRIMARY KEY ("address_internal_id"),    CONSTRAINT
  "address_customer_internal_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY
  ("customer_internal_id") REFERENCES "public"."customer"
  ("customer_internal_id")
- Contact_Information PRIMARY KEY ("contact_internal_id", "contact_type"),
  CONSTRAINT "contact_information_customer_internal_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("customer_internal_id") REFERENCES "public"."customer" ("customer_internal_id")
- External_Cards PRIMARY KEY ("customer_internal_id", "card_number"),
  CONSTRAINT "external_cards_customer_internal_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("customer_internal_id") REFERENCES "public"."customer" ("customer_internal_id")

The following indexes are in place:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_contact ON contact_information (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_address ON address (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_mkpref ON marketing_preferences (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_content ON content_type_preferences (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_cards ON external_cards (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cust_mcaid ON customer (mca_id);
```

This is the EXPLAIN from the query:

```
"Sort  (cost=103957.16..103957.20 rows=18 width=687)"
"  Sort Key: c.customer_internal_id, c0.contact_internal_id, c0.contact_type, a.address_internal_id, m.customer_internal_id, m.channel_id, c1.customer_internal_id, c1.channel_id, c1.type_id, e.customer_internal_id, e.card_number"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=35817.63..103956.78 rows=18 width=687)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=35813.32..103867.36 rows=6 width=631)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=35809.02..103833.42 rows=3 width=506)"
"                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=35808.74..103808.50 rows=3 width=433)"
"                          Hash Cond: (c0.customer_internal_id = c.customer_internal_id)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on contact_information c0  (cost=0.00..59117.35 rows=2368635 width=115)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=35808.73..35808.73 rows=1 width=318)"
"                                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=8.47..35808.73 rows=1 width=318)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (a.customer_internal_id = c.customer_internal_id)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on address a  (cost=0.00..31425.09 rows=1166709 width=148)"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=8.46..8.46 rows=1 width=170)"
"                                            ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=170)"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using idx_cust_mcaid on customer c  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=170)"
"                                                        Index Cond: ((mca_id)::text = '2701159742879@priceline.com.au'::text)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using external_cards_pkey on external_cards e  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=73)"
"                          Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on content_type_preferences c1  (cost=4.30..11.29 rows=2 width=125)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on content_type_preferences_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=2 width=0)"
"                          Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on marketing_preferences m  (cost=4.31..14.87 rows=3 width=56)"
"              Recheck Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on marketing_preferences_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.31 rows=3 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
```

It seems most of the cost is in these nested loop joins, but I'm not sure how to attack that problem. I did have a seq scan on customer originally, but I addressed that with an index on mca_id but it made virtually no difference to the execution time.

EDIT: Update. I added a couple of hash indexes to cater for the customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id JOINS,

```
CREATE INDEX idx_contact_hash ON contact_information USING hash (customer_internal_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_address_hash ON address USING hash (customer_internal_id);
```

And the query time has reduced to 70ms or so. This is GREAT, but I recall something about hash indexes being frowned upon, or not suggested for use? Can anyone help out? Here is the new analyze/explain

```
"Sort  (cost=119.30..119.33 rows=12 width=687) (actual time=0.082..0.082 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: c.customer_internal_id, c0.contact_internal_id, c0.contact_type, a.address_internal_id, m.customer_internal_id, m.channel_id, c1.customer_internal_id, c1.channel_id, c1.type_id, e.customer_internal_id, e.card_number"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=18"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=9.31..119.08 rows=12 width=687) (actual time=0.062..0.070 rows=2 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=18"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5.01..59.47 rows=4 width=631) (actual time=0.054..0.059 rows=2 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=14"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..36.85 rows=2 width=506) (actual time=0.045..0.048 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=10"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..24.79 rows=1 width=391) (actual time=0.039..0.040 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=8"
"                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.43..16.48 rows=1 width=318) (actual time=0.031..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=6"
"                                ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=170) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using idx_cust_mcaid on customer c  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=170) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Index Cond: ((mca_id)::text = '2701159742879@priceline.com.au'::text)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                                ->  Index Scan using idx_address_hash on address a  (cost=0.00..8.02 rows=1 width=148) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                          ->  Index Scan using external_cards_pkey on external_cards e  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=73) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                    ->  Index Scan using idx_contact_hash on contact_information c0  (cost=0.00..12.04 rows=2 width=115) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=2"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on content_type_preferences c1  (cost=4.30..11.29 rows=2 width=125) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=2)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on content_type_preferences_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=2)"
"                          Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=4"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on marketing_preferences m  (cost=4.31..14.87 rows=3 width=56) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=2)"
"              Recheck Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=4"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on marketing_preferences_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.31 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=2)"
"                    Index Cond: (c.customer_internal_id = customer_internal_id)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=4"
"Planning Time: 0.770 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.181 ms"
```

Answer (score 1):

Up to version 9.6, hash indexes were not crash safe and so were discouraged for that reason.  WAL was added to them in v10, so there is no longer anything wrong with using them.

Although they also shouldn't be necessary, and I see no reason the regular (btree) indexes were not being used.  Are you sure they were actually present and marked as valid?  Or maybe they were very bloated and could have been fixed with a `REINDEX INDEX ...` command, but it hard to see how they could be so bloated that they wouldn't have still been preferred over the seq scans.

Comment: How can I check that they are a) present and b) marked as valid? all I can report at this point is that after adding the aforementioned hash indexes, the query response time VASTLY improved.

Comment: If you use `psql`, the `\d tablename` command will show the table definition, along with a list of indexes, and label any invalid ones as INVALID.  You can also look at pg_catalog.pg_index.indisvalid.